# Is it possible to redefine params in a function within a function?

Tags: javascript

I can only change the code within `function a`. For example if I have:

`Object.define(window, 'App', {get: console.log.bind(null, 'World') });`

WeChat will take my code and turn it into:

```
const App = console.log.bind(null, 'Hello')

Object.defineProperty(window, 'App', {
  set: ()=> {
    console.error("You are not allow to modify App");
  }
})

const sandbox = (App, Function, window) => {
  'use strict';
  function a() {
    'use strict';
    // *** I can only modify codes within this block ***
    Object.define(window, 'App', {get: console.log.bind(null, 'World') });
    // *** I can only modify codes within this block ***
  }
  function b() {
    'use strict';
    App();
  }
  a();
  b();
};

sandbox(App, ()=>(()=>({})), undefined);
```

Now, I want to modify App in `function a`, so I can change its behavior in `function b`, so it would print `World` instead of `Hello`.

Comment: `App = 'newAppVal'` ? You can use `Object.defineProperty` to define getters/etc *on* an object, eg if `App` is an object and you want to change what happens when `App.foo` is accessed

Comment: Is there any reason for a simple assignment not working?

Comment: "*is it possible to redefine the getter*" - `App` is a plain variable, introduced by the parameter declaration. There is no getter.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the setters of App and Page have been modified.

Answer (score 1):

You've commented on this answer to say:

> Let me clarify. I can only change codes within the `function(func)`. The rest of the codes are generated by WeChat.

There's nothing you can do within that function to turn the `App` and `Page` parameters of the function it's declared within into getters.

---

It looks like you're trying to replace a parameter with a getter for it, perhaps so you can observe when the code reads it. No, you can't do that, because parameters aren't properties of an object.¹

You could, of course, define an object with a getter and use that object within the function body instead of directly using the parameter:

```
function(App, Page) {
    const params = {
        get App() {
            // ...observe the read...
            return App;
        },
        get Page() {
            // ...observe the read...
            return Page;
        }
    };

    // Use `params.App` and `params.Page` in the body of the function.
}
```

...but it's fairly convoluted.

(**Ugh.** I just realized that in loose mode, if you wrapped the function body with `with (params) { /*...*/ }`, `App` and `Page` would resolve to the object properties and trigger the getter. [Has to be loose mode because strict mode disallows `with`.] Please don't do that except, perhaps, briefly as a debugging tactic. :-) )

---

¹ *(At least, not one accessible to your code. They are conceptually bindings in a lexical environment object, but 1. bindings aren't properties [though they're similar], 2. that's conceptual, actual JavaScript engines likely optimize that away, and 3. lexical environment objects aren't accessible to JavaScript code [not least so that they can be optimized away]. :-) )*

Comment: Let me clarify. I can only change codes within the function(func). The rest of the codes are generated by WeChat.

Comment: Also I have full control over this function scope but I must change the global behavior so other developers can use my modified App and Page within importing code in all of their Javascript files.

Comment: @AeroWang - If you can only put code in that function, no, you can't turn `App` and `Page` in its parent function into getters. I've added that to the top of the answer.

Comment: That's what I thought. Simply cannot fulfill this requirement.